# Copying a file from a directory to another directory in the same domain could not work.

Tags: php, html, copy

My issue is that I am trying to copy a index.html file from a directory to another directory in my web application using PHP copy(). 
It can copy when they are in the same directory but when i try to copy it to another directory with chmod 777 permission then nothing happened. 
Below is my src code. I want to copy the index.html from folder template1 to another folder called users but it would not copy over.

```
CopyIndexHtml.php
<?php
 $src='./builder/template/template1/index.html';
 $des='./builder/users/index.html';
 copy($src,$des);
?>
```

Comment: Check the logs. Check the return value of `copy()`. Don't use relative paths, use absolute paths instead: `__DIR__ . '/../path/to/builder/...'`

Comment: You may want to check the errors thrown. After the copy: `$errors = error_get_last(); echo $errors['message'];`

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov Thank for the advise, appreciate it , cheers

Comment: @varlogtim Thank for the advise, appreciate it , cheers

Answer (score 0):

First define constants in index file of your project

```
define('DIR_PATH', __DIR__);
```

after this function use

```
    echo $source = str_replace('\\', '/', DIR_PATH) . "/image.jpg";
    echo "<br>";
    echo $dest  = str_replace('\\', '/', DIR_PATH) . "/uploads/image.jpg";
    copy($source,$dest);
```